# Error Handlers for SpecialCell fundtions in excel VBA

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I'm having some issues on how to use the error handlers. Please see the code below. Basically I would like to find out the blank cells for each row in an iteration and if found, color them with yellow(44) and give a dialog box at the end (I'm adding a integer and if greater than 1 it returns a dialog box) this is anther problem How do I skip this during error handling? So I used SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) to find the blank cells. So when there are no blank cells it's an error according to the above function. I'm not sure how properly I am using the error handlers. Can anyone give an input here please.

```
Sub checkblankcells()
Dim i, j, k, error, error1, error2, lastRow, LastCol As Long
Dim item, cntr As String
Dim r As Range
error2 = 0
lastRow = Range("D65000").End(xlUp).row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Import").Activate
Dim counter As Long
For i = 1 To lastRow
    With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    Set r = Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, LastCol))
    On Error GoTo Check1
    r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    error2 = error2 + 1
    Check1:
    Resume Next
    Next
    'Deleting the Blank cell Check Numbers at the end of each row.
    lastRow = Range("D65000").End(xlUp).row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Import").Activate
    For i = 1 To lastRow
    With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   End With
   Cells(i, LastCol).Select
   Selection.Clear
   Next
   If error2 > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Blank Activities in Yellow. Check Schedules", vbCritical, "TIL"
 Exit Sub
  End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An `On Error GoTo <label>` function works like any `GoTo` function: it just take executor of code to another line, when error occurs. There is some hidden variable `Err`, which changes value, whenever some error occur. It have value `0` by default, when everything is fine, and some specific error code value, when error occurs during executing your code. So, instead of creating variable `error2`, do it like this:

```
Sub checkblankcells()
Dim i, j, k, lastRow, LastCol As Long
Dim item, cntr As String
Dim r As Range
lastRow = Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Import").Activate
Dim counter As Long
For i = 1 To lastRow
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    Set r = Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, LastCol))
    On Error GoTo Check1
    r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 44
Next i
    'Deleting the Blank cell Check Numbers at the end of each row.
    lastRow = Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Import").Activate
For i = 1 To lastRow
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    Cells(i, LastCol).Select
    Selection.Clear
Next i

Check1:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Blank Activities in Yellow. Check Schedules", vbCritical, "TIL"
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't have your workbook and I can not test this code, so I might forgot something, even tho, I'm sure you can see the idea of using `Err` variable.

Comment: I picked your idea to keep the error handler simple. Used the resume next just to color cells which were blank and resume if no blank cells, not worrying about counting how many blank cells.  Once all the iterations are done. I ran anther loop to read cells with colored and then put a counter if condition met and reported that. To answer your question yes i want the colors to remain so the user knows where he missed the data.

Comment: Sorry, I get lost. Have this soulution worked for you, or you have some problems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've done this exactly as you did, but this works (I think)! I didn't include the deletion of blank cell check numbers as I don't understand the context of the sheet, and would probably delete something important - you can incorporate that yourself. This also clears the colour of all cells before, something you might not want. I didn't quite know what else you wanted, so let me know if necessary. Good luck!

```
Sub ColourEmpties()
        Dim myRange As Range
        Dim x As Long
        Dim y As Long

Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
x = ActiveCell.Column

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
y = ActiveCell.Row

 On Error GoTo Done

    'clear all color
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(y, x)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    'color only blank cells
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(y, x)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 44

     MsgBox "Blank Activities in Yellow. Check Schedules"

Done:

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but i figured it out. What I did was first fill in the blank cells with color on error resume next. Once all the iterations are done. I ran anther loop to read cells with colored and then put a counter if condition met and reported that. To answer your question yes i want the colors to remain so the user knows where he missed the data.

Comment: Aha! I didn't understand that you wanted the number of errors counted as well. Good luck!